# Ignore area on touchpad

Tags: linux, debian, mouse, touchpad

I recently purchased a Lenovo y500 and installed Debian wheezy 64-bit on it with no issues.  The problem I'm having is with the touchpad.  In Windows (dual boot) it ignores movements on the lower part of the track pad which is used for clicking.  In Debian however, the entire touchpad is detected for movements.  Thus, when I click, it responds the the slight movements I make on the touchpad while pushing it down.  This is especially bothersome when right clicking which often results in my inadvertently selecting a menu option when I release the button.

Is there some way I can configure Debian to ignore movements on a certain area of the touchpad?

Comment: The info in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1386578) might be helpful for Debian too.

Comment: @Karan this kinda works but it then reads all of my right clicks as left clicks.  weird.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can achieve this with:

```
$ synclient AreaBottomEdge=1822
```

After this I could not paint an area of text by clicking the button and moving another finger on the mouse pad. The result is not identical to a touchpad with buttons that are not part of the pad. The cursor does not move when the button area of the touchpad is touched regardless of the movement of the other finger.

More information: [Arch Linux info on Synaptics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics)

And naturally:

```
$ man synaptics
```

I hope someone could give a better solution, but I hope this helps you to get started.